# Getting Table/View Exists error when running laravel dusk tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I have setup homestead environment for laravel. I am using the latest version of laravel(5.4). Whenever i run the command php artisan dusk, i get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Browser\auth\LawyerRegisterTest::lawyer_can_register
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'court_user' already exists (SQL: create table    `court_user` (`court_id` int not null, `user_id` int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

Do i have to reset the migrations everytime i run the dusk tests?

Comment: Check you have "court_user" table already in your database?

Comment: if you have `court_user` table in your database delete it and run dusk again

Comment: @Onix So i have to do this everytime i run dusk tests?

Comment: Take a look here i hope it helps you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk

Comment: Laravel dusk has a very confusing documentation